# using JQuery().text() returning int with string

Tags: jquery

I'm getting a return value for this query that doesn't make sense.

code is:

```
var option = $(":selected").text();
```

result:

```
10   Activity
```

can anyone tell me why I'm getting back a 10 and spaces and how to get rid of them?

html:

```
<select name="datagrid_filter" onchange="startFilter(this);">
<option>All</option>
<option disabled="true">Assignment:</option>
<option disabled="true">Client:</option>
<option disabled="true">Type:</option>
    <option class="type" value="Activity"> &nbsp Activity</option>
    <option class="type" value="Alert"> &nbsp Alert</option>
    <option class="type" value="Lead"> &nbsp Lead</option>
    <option class="type" value="Notification"> &nbsp Notification</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what does your html look like

Comment: Post the html of the thing you are selecting

Comment: show us html code please

Comment: @zzlalani If you're going to edit a post for "proper formatting", try not to 1) introduce grammatical errors, and 2) destroy the result string due to blockquote condensing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9yZNz/1/)

You can remove unwanted spaces using the the function:

```
jQuery.trim( str )
```

regarding the "10" if you have other `<select>` the page, to avoid problems, refer directly to the `<select name="datagrid_filter">` by name

```
$("select[name='datagrid_filter'] option:selected").text()
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Didn't know I that by not calling it directly could cause an issue with the result. Problem is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

.text() returns the text value, which is a string.
You could apply parseInt() to it, or alternatively look for the .val()

eg.

```
var option = parseInt( $(":selected").text(), 10 );
```

or

```
 var option = $(":selected").val()
```

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, I'm pretty sure this is NOT what the OP is trying to do. They seem to be trying to get the option's ***TEXT***, which is something I do quite commonly too for a number of reasons. Also second parameter to `parseInt` is missing.